SearchIndexAsync invalid nextToken
I have simple request C# for SearchIndexAsync aws SDK. First time receive response with 'nextToken' field for request other page. I use nextToken value, but receive 'Invalid nextToken'
I perform same request by aws cli and it's working fine.
My code:
SearchIndexResponse response = await _iotClient.SearchIndexAsync(new SearchIndexRequest
{
    QueryString = queryString,
    MaxResults = maxResults,
    NextToken = nextToken
});

_iotClient is IAmazonIoT
Exception
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleExceptionStream(IRequestContext requestContext, IWebResponseData httpErrorResponse, HttpErrorResponseException exception, Stream responseStream)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleExceptionAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.HandleAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessExceptionAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)

Update:
Response Log. I add 'xxxx' for privacy response
AmazonIoTClient 67|2024-12-02T15:38:31.771Z|DEBUG|Received response (truncated to 1024 bytes): [{"nextToken":"AQJnif/ptPp6otTULTCYZu3eV0Be458dLpq/pnT+pHC4bZjcDbBIiRNCLJ9PH7x9xCCIqQDMU0k4gbr+a3CHoMxs+yFnId9gdG2f+FnYFQc3xgSyj7jAyxNdXbN9izAC7KjfAgjs5Xw4smIK50bz3SBbGhrOc6u9eDK3A7qWXpUnsBzr4yh76ds5mfr/WeouzanV+aDz+RR/Gg==","thingGroups":null,"things":[{"attributes":{"xxxxx":"xxxxx","domain":"xx","id":"xxxxxx","ring":"xxx","type":"xxxx","vin":"xxxxxx"},"connectivity":{"connected":false,"disconnectReason":null,"timestamp":0},"deviceDefender":null,"shadow":"","thingGroupNames":["xxxxx","xxxxx","xxxxxx"],"thingId":"00001f4c-25f8-4d59-9906-6b0c26508c60","thingNam]

I use nextToken for the second request, not working and I have this error:
AmazonIoTClient 58|2024-12-02T15:36:19.097Z|ERROR|InvalidRequestException making request SearchIndexRequest to https://iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/. Attempt 2. --> Amazon.IoT.Model.InvalidRequestException: Invalid nextToken

